# Is encoding parameter case insensitive in WebView related use

Tags: android, utf-8, character-encoding, android-webview

I came across both spelling, `"UTF-8"` and `"utf-8"` as an `encoding` value in WebView related methods' parameters, e.g.

```
new WebResourceResponse("text/javascript", "UTF-8", inputStream);

webView.loadData(getHtml(), "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Is it case insensitive? 
Can't find a list of possible encodings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `encoding` parameter is actually a misleading one.

When used in the context of the `loadData` function, it's only used by the WebView to determine whether the `data` is base-64 encoded or not. So it's value is meaningless unless you are passing base-64 encoded content, when it must be `"base64"` (and should be lower case).

The case of the charset set in WebResourceResponse is case-insensitive.